# No module named _caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

`_caffe.so` is present in the `caffe/python/caffe` folder

Have set the path variable as `export PYTHONPATH=/home/itstudent1/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH`.

`make pycaffe` was also successful.

I am not understanding what else might be the cause for this error. I am able to import caffe in python.

> File
>   "/home/itstudent1/MajorProject/densecap-master/lib/tools/../../python/caffe/pycaffe.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \ ImportError: No module named _caffe

Comment: are you running the command inside the caffe root folder? have you set the path in .bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have two versions of caffe:
one in `/home/itstudent1/caffe` and another in `/home/itstudent1/MajorProject/densecap-master`.
While the first version is built and compiled, the later is not and your `import` looks for `_caffe.so` in the later.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.